# Objective-C or Python key logger for osx

Tags: objective-c, macos, keylogger

I manage 300 macbook computers running OSX Mavericks and I would like to develop a key logger either in python or Objective-c.  The point of this is to ultimately output log files to a local server so that I can do a scan for "key words"  If a word like "Suicide" or "Sex" comes up i can research the context.

Any guidance to help me get started would be amazing.

if it is any help I did find this code for python but could not make it work.  I am sure if I just get a basic system running I can make the rest work the way I need it to.

```
from AppKit import NSApplication, NSApp
from Foundation import NSObject, NSLog
from Cocoa import NSEvent, NSKeyDownMask
from PyObjCTools import AppHelper

class AppDelegate(NSObject):
    def applicationDidFinishLaunching_(self, notification):
        mask = NSKeyDownMask
        NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask_handler_(mask, handler)

def handler(event):
    try:
        NSLog(u"%@", event)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        AppHelper.stopEventLoop()

def main():
    app = NSApplication.sharedApplication()
    delegate = AppDelegate.alloc().init()
    NSApp().setDelegate_(delegate)
    AppHelper.runEventLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: As written this question is far too broad: We can’t write an entire application for you. You’ll have better luck here if you break your development into short, focused questions, with explanations of the behavior you want, the code you’ve written, and the actual effects of the code.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEvent/addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask%3ahandler%3a) states:

> Key-related events may only be monitored if accessibility is enabled or if your application is trusted for accessibility access (see [`AXIsProcessTrusted`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ApplicationServices/Reference/AXUIElement_header_reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AXIsProcessTrusted)).

You can enable accessibility in System Preferences, on the Universal Access pane, option "Enable access for assistive devices".